# PowerShell Export-CSV - Missing Columns

Tags: powershell, export-csv

This is a follow-up question from [PowerShell | EVTX | Compare Message with Array (Like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479611/powershell-evtx-compare-message-with-array-like)

I changed the tactic slightly, now I am collecting all the services installed,

```
$7045 = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Path="1system.evtx"; Id = 7045 } | select 
@{N=’Timestamp’; E={$_.TimeCreated.ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}},
Id, 
@{N=’Machine Name’; E={$_.MachineName}},
@{N=’Service Name’; E={$_.Properties[0].Value}},@{N=’Image Path’;E=$_.Properties[1].Value}},
@{N=’RunAsUser’; E={$_.Properties[4].Value}},@{N=’Installed By’; E={$_.UserId}}
```

Now I match each object for any suspicious traits and if found, I add a column 'Suspicious' with the value 'Yes'. This is because I want to leave the decision upto the analyst and pretty sure the bad guys might use something we've not seen before.

```
foreach ($Evt in $7045)
{
if ($Evt.'Image Path' -match $sus)
    {

    $Evt | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Suspicious' -Value 'Yes'

    }
}
```

Now, I'm unable to get PowerShell to display all columns unless I specifically `Select` them

```
$7045 | Format-Table
```

Same goes for CSV Export. The first two don't include the `Suspicious` Column but the third one does but that's because I'm explicitly asking it to.

```
$7045 | select * | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoTypeInformation
$7045 | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoTypeInformation
$7045 | Select-Object Timestamp, Id, 'Machine Name', 'Service Name', 'Image Path', 'RunAsUser', 'Installed By', Suspicious | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I read the Export-CSV documentation on MS. Searched StackOverFlow for some tips, I think it has something to do with PS checking the first Row and then compares if the property exists for the second row and so on.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed). See also [`#13906` Add `-UnifyProperties` parameter to Select-Object](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13906)

Comment: Yes it does, iRon! I'll watch the thread and thank you for sharing it with me. so kind. Much helpful. wow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is partially because of how objects are displayed to the console, the first object's **Properties** determines the displayed **Properties (Columns)** for all objects.

The bigger problem though, is that [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) will **not export** those properties that **do not match with first object's properties** unless they're explicitly added to the remaining objects or the objects are reconstructed, one easy way to achieve this is to use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) as you have pointed out in the question.

**Given the following example:**

```bash
$test = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        A = 'ValA'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        A = 'ValA'
        B = 'ValB'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        C = 'ValC'
        D = 'ValD'
        E = 'ValE'
    }
)
```

- [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2) will not display the properties **B to E**:

```bash
$test | Format-Table

A
-
ValA
ValA
```

- [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-7.2) can display the objects properly, this is because each property with it's corresponding value has it's own console line in the display:

```bash
PS /> $test | Format-List

A : ValA

A : ValA
B : ValB

C : ValC
D : ValD
E : ValE
```

- [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.2) will also miss properties **B to E**:

```bash
$test | ConvertTo-Csv

"A"
"ValA"
"ValA"
```

You have different options as a workaround for this, you could either add the `Suspicious` property to **all objects** and for those events that are not suspicious you could add `$null` as *Value*.

Another workaround is to use `Select-Object` explicitly calling the `Suspicious` property (this works because you know the property is there and you know it's **Name**).

If you did not know **how many properties your objects had**, a dynamic way to solve this would be to discover their properties using the [`PSObject` intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject).

```bash
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

function ConvertTo-NormalizedObject {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [object[]] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        $list  = [List[object]]::new()
        $props = [HashSet[string]]::new([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    }
    process {
        foreach($object in $InputObject) {
            $list.Add($object)
            foreach($property in $object.PSObject.Properties) {
                $null = $props.Add($property.Name)
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        $out = [ordered]@{}
        foreach ($object in $list) {
            foreach ($prop in $props) {
                $out[$prop] = $object.$prop
            }

            [pscustomobject] $out
            $out.Clear()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```bash
# From Pipeline
$test | ConvertTo-NormalizedObject | Format-Table
# From Positional / Named parameter binding
ConvertTo-NormalizedObject $test | Format-Table
```

- Lastly, a pretty easy way of doing it thanks to [`Select-Object -Unique`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-4-select-unique-characters-from-an-array):

```bash
$prop = $test.ForEach{ $_.PSObject.Properties.Name } | Select-Object -Unique
$test | Select-Object $prop
```

Using `$test` for this example, the result would become:

```bash
A    B    C    D    E
-    -    -    -    -
ValA
ValA ValB
          ValC ValD ValE
```

Comment: Thank you both of you, it solidifies my understanding around this concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I want to warn that the Select-Object -Unique can be tricky, I ran in an issue that I found out that the order of the properties is not always the same, resulting in different CSV order headers, which broke my import ;)

Comment: @sjorspa are you sure this was `Select-Object -Unique` and not `Sort-Object -Unique` ? Order should not be affected by `Select-Object`, if it actually did it smells like a bug. In any case the recommended would be to use the methods using the `HashSet<T>`

Comment: Too make it clear, I used the same Function on different sets, so I think this can just happen, in the end I just took the desired fields and added them manually, it is also faster, because it where huge collections of 100.000 large JSON objects, it is working for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70480299/9898643), you can add a column `Suspicious` straight away if you take out the `Where-Object` filter and simply add another calculated property to the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
# create a regex for the suspicious executables:
$sus = '(powershell|cmd|psexesvc)\.exe'
# alternatively you can join the array items like this:
# $sus = ('powershell.exe','cmd.exe','psexesvc.exe' | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

$7045 = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'System';Id = 7045 } | 
        Select-Object Id, 
                      @{N='Timestamp';E={$_.TimeCreated.ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}}, 
                      @{N='Machine Name';E={$_.MachineName}},
                      @{N='Service Name'; E={$_.Properties[0].Value}},
                      @{N='Image Path'; E={$_.Properties[1].Value}},
                      @{N='RunAsUser'; E={$_.Properties[4].Value}},
                      @{N='Installed By'; E={$_.UserId}},
                      @{N='Suspicious'; E={
                        if ($_.Properties[1].Value -match $sus) { 'Yes' } else {'No'} 
                      }}

$7045 | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Services.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Because you have many columns, this will not fit the console width anymore if you do `$7045 | Format-Table`, but the CSV file will hold all columns you wanted.
I added switch `-UseCulture` to the Export-Csv cmdlet, which makes sure you can simply double-click the csv file so it opens correctly in your Excel.

As sidenote: Please do not use those curly so-called 'smart-quotes' in code as they may lead to unforeseen errors. Straighten these `’` thingies and use normal double or single quotes (`"` and `'`)