# Including all properties of all objects in an inconsistent list

Tags: powershell

I have a list of objects that can have an unknown set of properties like this:

```
$list = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{ Name='Pork';   Type='Meat' },
  [pscustomobject]@{ Name='Orange'; Type='Fruit'
    SubType='Berry'  ## extra property
  }, 
  [pscustomobject]@{ Name='Peanut'; Type='Nut'
    Salty=$true      ## extra property
  },
  [pscustomobject]@{ Name='Gumball'; Type='Candy'
    $Foo.Name = $Foo.Value  ## extra property with unknown name
  }
)
```

It's not a "good" data structure, but it's something I run into now and then when doing things like `Add-Member` in reports, searching through WMI, or dealing with other cmdlets that can return multiple similar object types.

The problem I have is in displaying all the objects in a table and/or exporting them, like to a CSV. Many cmdlets like `Select-Object` **only** include the members of the first object in the list, and leave out other properties:

```sh
$list | Format-Table -Property *  ## only displays first object's properties: Name,Type

Name    Type 
----    ---- 
Pork    Meat 
Orange  Fruit
Peanut  Nut  
Gumball Candy

# other examples:
$list | Get-Member                ## Only lists two NoteProperties
$list | Select-Object -Property * ## same as Format-Table
$list | Export-Csv test.csv       ## only exports first two properties

## Actually does display all properties:
$list | Format-List
```

If I know my data might come in this way, what can I do to "fix" it before continuing? For example, how could I force `$list | Export-Csv` to include all properties?

Comment: See: [not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/1701026): `$List |UnifyProperties |Format-List`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70484662/powershell-export-csv-missing-columns/70484836#70484836 also relevant

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks! The easy way you suggested there is what I was looking for: `$prop = $test.ForEach{ $_.PSObject.Properties.Name } | Select-Object -Unique` and `$test | Select-Object $prop`

Comment: Bear in mind, `Select-Object -Unique` does not use OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: I believe the question was already addressed, if anything let me know and i'll re-open